# Find the right architecture for dashboard analytic visualization

Tags: visualization

I have multiple sensors that are sending up to 10 data a day (temperature, battery,  others data related to any event that could occur).

In the future I may have hundreds, thousands of sensors that are sending up these data.

I still try to understand what would be the best architecture and Database that I could use for my project.

Basically I was considering :

Devices [1...N] ==> HTTP API ==> Data processing ==> Database ==> HTTP API ==> Front end visualization.

First, what do you think of this architecture ?
The visualization dashboard will be simple : some metrics and alerts if something occurs. It need to be actualized every time a data is received.

Then, I still thinking which kind of database should I use. So far, it's not really big data but over time, it can be (hundred of sensors sending multiples data a data every day).

I was thinking about Time Series Database like InfluxDB, MongoDB (NoSQL) or Postgresql (SQL).

It still the fog for me. Could you please help by giving me an insight about the best thing to get it start ?

Comment: `best thing` is a nonsense specification ... it means different thing to different people .... try using `google sheets` to get started ... http://embedded-lab.com/blog/post-data-google-sheets-using-esp8266/ ...

Comment: Have you looked at MQTT? Node Red?

Comment: Look at the related question on the right; they might be of some help.